# Calling a method within an axios get forEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to call `GetLikes(item.id)` method which is in a `forEach` and within my `axios.get` function. I get back an error stating `TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetLikes' of undefined`.

If I comment the method I can see that I'm able to get all items and their ids however when I uncomment the method it no longer works.

```
axios
  .get("/api/endpoint")
  .then(response => {
    this.data = response.data;
    this.data.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log("found: ", item)
      console.log("found id: ", item.id)
      this.GetLikes(item.id);
    });
  })
```

Output with code above:
**It seems that it cannot get id 1 for some reason although the same code gets id 1 just without the method below**

```
found:  {…}
found id:  2
TypeError: Cannot read property 'GetLikes' of undefined
```

Output with this.GetLikes(item.id) being commented out:

```
found:  {…}
found id:  2
found:  {…}
found id:  1
```

**^Above clearly can get all the items so why do I get an undefined if I try to call a method on those items?**

The below code works (it gets the correct likes). I use this when a user presses like however I also need to initially get all the likes which is what I'm trying to do above.

```
Like(id) {
  axios
    .post("/like/" + id)
    .then(response => {
      this.GetLikes(id);
    })
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe `this` in `this.GetLikes` doesn't refer to the scope you think it does when using `forEach(function(item) {`

Comment: @AndrewLohr how would I go about debugging this?

Comment: I wrote an answer for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
this.data.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log("found: ", item)
      console.log("found id: ", item.id)
      this.GetLikes(item.id);
    });
```

The above code creates a new scope for `this` so you get `property 'GetLikes' of undefined` for the function scope of `forEach`

You don't get this problem with

```
  axios
    .post("/like/" + id)
    .then(response => {
      this.GetLikes(id);
    })
```

because ES6 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not bind their own `this`

You can try doing

```
axios
  .get("/api/endpoint")
  .then(response => {
    this.data = response.data;
    this.data.forEach((item) => {
      console.log("found: ", item)
      console.log("found id: ", item.id)
      this.GetLikes(item.id);
    });
  })
```

which won't bind `this` in the `forEach` loop (notice the arrow function)

Comment: Thank you @AndrewLohr. I had the same issue with another method and it seems I've completely forgotten my mistakes from the past!

Comment: @AndrewLohr np, you answered right when you answered :)

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions for the `forEach` as it binds this to the containing scope.

```
axios
  .get("/api/endpoint")
  .then(response => {
    this.data = response.data;
    this.data.forEach((item) => {
      console.log("found: ", item)
      console.log("found id: ", item.id)
      this.GetLikes(item.id);
    });
  })
```